# Remove Rich Snippets by default magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4, rich-snippets

Remove Rich Snippets by default magento 2.4.2

I am using a third party module for structured data and I want to disable the ones that come by default in magento.

It is possible from the backend to disable this function. Specifically, I want to remove the structured data referring to the store that appears on all the pages of my website.

Thanks!